# How to add CocoaSPDY to ModernHttpClient

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, spdy

[ModernHttpClient](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient) is great, but so is CocoaSPDY. I want to know how do I use them together?

Answer (score 0):

This was never answered, but CocoaSPDY is now unnecessary as of iOS 8.0, NSUrlSession does this automatically